# Split WS2812B controlling each branch as if one contiguous strip

Tags: led, signal, led-strip

I have an output which can control 90 WS2812B LEDs. I have 3x 30 LED WS2812B strips. I cannot daisy chain the signal from these strips. What would be the easiest way to take a 90 LED signal, have the signal for 1-30 output on the first strip (as 1-30), 31-60 for the next strip (as 1-30) and 61-90 for the final strip (as 1-30)?

EDIT: please note power is not an issue and for clarity "I cannot daisy chain the signal from these strips"

Comment: Define 'easiest'. Is using an MCU to pipeline the signals to the two later strips 'easy'?

Comment: If that's the way, that's the way. Easier would be an off the shelf device for this very thing, but if it's microcontroller and go custom then that's it.

Comment: "off the shelf" ... the only think I can think of to strip the first 30 signals from a WS2812 signal ... is a 30-long strip of WS2812 devices.  Perhaps you have extras, perhaps you can find very low power ones.  A microcontroller looks a lot better than that, if you have the knowledge and facilities.

Comment: I have 4x 90 LED signals and 12x 30 LED devices, so if an MC is the way to go it's time to order an Uno R3 for the number of digital pins and get programming with FastLED.

Comment: I believe boxes that already do this exist so it would be simplest to buy these.

Comment: @Justme great - can you name one?

Comment: @Metalshark No because it is off topic to ask and suggest what to buy. These boxes are used in LED curtains that draw pixelated images, so I don't know what they are called.

Comment: One output to 3 inputs in is not unusual. Arduino is based on ATMega128 MCU, check the spec. Just do not power the strips from the board, use separate power source.

Comment: For anyone looking in the future reading the signal at 800khz is a real pain and you might want to find a site where answering the question isn't off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a microcontroller with three outputs and write a function in software that maps pixels 0-29 to output 0, 30-59 to output 1 and 60-89 to output 2.